# Minimizing a function and checking if optimality condition

Tags: calculus, optimization

I have a question for

$$f(x) = x+ \sqrt{1-x^2}$$

It is clear by inspection that $x= -1$ is the minimum,  because for the square root. If we have $x$ smaller then we have an imaginary number, if x is larger, then the second term can be only positive and add to the total value. My question is that we generally have an optimality condition that says $f'(x^*) = 0$, for continuously differentiable. But

$$f'(x) = 1 - \frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

and if we say $x \rightarrow -1$ then we get
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow -1} f'(x)= 1 -  \frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$
which gives us undefined. So the reason the optimality condition does not hold is because we are not differentiable at $-1$?

Comment: You set the first derivative to zero and solve for $x$, you get x=+/- 0.5. Next, you check the 2nd derivative if is positive, negative or zero at those points. No limits required to determine extremes.

Answer (score 1):

Since your domain is the closed interval [-1,1], you need to check the value of your function at the endpoints as well as checking for local minimizers. You do not need to check derivatives at endpoints.